# Few Questions regarding Translational Kinetic energy of a ideal gas molecule

Tags: energy, ideal-gas

The translational kinetic energy of an ideal gas molecule is 3/2KT. In our physics class, the teacher brought up a question about where the has molecule will stop. he equated 3/2KT to ½MV<sup>2</sup> . In the question temperature was constant.

If this gas molecule is moving up from the surface of the earth with 3/2KT kinetic energy why will it stop after reaching a height "h"? if temperature is constant then Kinetic energy is also constant. The molecule should never stop imo. But the teacher just uses the change in KE = change in PE and gets height.

Comment: temperature is a statistical quantity dependent on a large number of particles. Kinetic and potential energy characterize single particles. Kinetic energy would be constant if there were no gravitation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your teacher is making a critical error in trying to teach you about the relation between temperature and kinetic energy this way. First of all, temperature is generally not well-defined for small systems like one particle, as it is a statistical quantity derived from the properties of large ensembles.

But putting that aside and accepting the translational kinetic energy of an ideal gas particle as $\frac{1}{2}kT$, this question is still ludicrous. The temperature could not possibly be constant, as the kinetic energy of the particle coming to rest is not constant. The reason the kinetic energy changes in the gravitational field is due to the work done by gravity on the massive particle when bringing it to rest. In the case that gravity were to actually bring the particle fully to rest, you could argue that the particle effectively has reached a temperature of absolute zero. Now, there are more nuanced and technical problems with this picture, but that is missing the point here. It is also possible that you mistook the teacher to be saying the temperature was fixed when it really wasn’t, as there is no way for the temperature so-defined can remain unchanged when the kinetic energy is clearly being lost.

Comment: actually i made a typo , i meant translational ke as 3/2KT . sorry my bad. 
question is "A He atom 300K is released from the surface of the earth to travel upward. Assuming that it undergoes no collision with other molecule, how high will it be before coming to the rest?"

Comment: That’s ok. The rule is you get $0.5kT$ translational energy for each degree of freedom. In this case, it’s like the particle is confined to 1-D, ha. But you can also do it with the new fraction. In any case, it’s a terrible question, but there’s no reason based on the wording to think the temperature is fixed. That just gives you a starting KE.